# Version control for ReportingServices

Tags: version-control, reportingservices-2005

How would go about implementing version control for Msft Reporting Services? Ideally we would like to have some sort of way of getting artifacts into our Subversion repository.

We can maintain the report definition files into the repos, but is there a better way of going about keeping a RS solution under version control?